# How can I get the rownum in the jpa?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a table name is t_user_score,like this:

```
id   name   score
1    alice   15
2    bob     13
3    tom     17
```

I want get the user's rank order by the score.

For example, I want get bob's rank. In the SQL, I can use :

```
select rank from 
     (select rownum as rank, id, name, score from t_user_score order by score)
where id = 2
```

But by use JPA, I don't know how can do this.

Comment: Why you need a field to do that? If you put results in a List your 'rownum' is the list index

Comment: I think your SQL won't work as it will always return 1 (due to the where condition) and anyway, the rownum is applied before order-by, so it would not work. Which doesn't answer your question, of course ...

Comment: If I get all the list from db, the performance will be too bad.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686915/jpa-calculating-ranking-from-ordered-selection

Comment: @rghome Tks, May be need a subquery.

Comment: For performance issue use pagination, otherwise you had to use nativeQuery

Comment: Those things are not supported by Hibernate/JPA. Have a native SQL execute directly on the database.

Answer (score 2):

In conclusion, JPA is not support to do this. If want get the rank, use nativeQuery.

Answer (score 0):

`select * from t_user where id = 2 order by score`

it will return you a list and size itself of list will be rownum.

Answer (score 0):

List list = list.stream().limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList());

use above way